# Error in gsub when applied to few data points

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I need to remove numbers repeating continuously in he sequence.

```
 a      b
Kor 66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 
        73.42 > 66.73 > 73.42 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 
        66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73
```

I need the out put like below

```
a       b
Kor 66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 
        73.42 > 66.73 > 73.42 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73 > 
        66.73 > 66.73 > 66.73
```

I need the below output

```
c= 66.73 > 73.42 > 66.73 > 73.42 > 66.73
```

But I am getting error in the output

```
66.73 > 73.42 > 66.73.42 > 66.73
```

I used the below code

```
c$c <- gsub("\\b([\\w\\.]+)( > \\1\\b)+","\\1",c$b,perl = T)
```

Comment: Hi Team , Can someone help me solve this issue

Comment: Help us to help you, use `dput` to obtain a reproducible piece of code and share with us.

Answer (score 1):

Your `[\\w\\.]+` pattern matches 1 or more digits, letters or dots, and it can match `54` in `12.54 >`54.12`. You need to make sure you match a float value while making a dot an obligatory part of the pattern.

You may use

```
sapply(str_extract_all(gsub("\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+)(?:\\s+>\\s+\\1\\b)+", "\\1", x), "\\d+\\.\\d+"), paste, collapse=" > ")
## => [1] "66.73 > 73.42 > 66.73 > 73.42 > 66.73"
```

With `gsub("\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+)(?:\\s+>\\s+\\1\\b)+", "\\1", x)`, you remove all the duplicate consecutive float numbers, and with `str_extract_all(x1, "\\d+\\.\\d+")` you can extract those numbers that are left, and then `paste` all the found values with `" > "` substring.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, After executing the code, I am getting only "" "" "",

Comment: @Rperfect Then you have some other input than you posted. Please [share an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Wiktor. Thanks for this. It is working. However, for few codes where there is single value(say 97), the output is showing as 0, instead of 97

Comment: @Rperfect Please provide a regex fiddle  with the text that fails. [Here is my `gsub` regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/sWLF9P/1).

Comment: Ok I will try. But may i know why it is showing as 0?

Comment: May I know what i am supposed to do. I am not getting